# Performance problems using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA in my web application (hibernate is the vendor) and I am confused regarding performance of queries.
In my code I use the following query:

```
select c.id from Cdr c where c.receivedOn >= :start and c.receivedOn < :end and c.buy.id in (:buyList)
```

Running this query against the DB directly takes 0.1 seconds to execute.
Running this through the server takes a few minutes, what am I missing here?

here is the query generated by the java:

```
select cdr0_.id as col_0_0_ from billing_cdr cdr0_ where cdr0_.received_on>=? and cdr0_.received_on<? and (cdr0_.buy_id in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?))
```

Comment: Did you activate tracing, how does the native SQL query look like?

Comment: @home i added the generated query

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this link

[How to improve JPA performance](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html)

was really helpful to me.

**Edit:**
Dont be confused about performance of queries. because its the first time need. if you think about data cache is implemented by persistence providers (JPA) in order to improve performance by reducing accesses to the database data. Just think about When millions of users pretend to access the same row of a table they usually went to open a connection to the database and then the data was
retrieved from the table, in this sense
the database became a bottleneck for many applications;
that is why data caching is of primary importance for new
Web applications; in this sense, the Java Persistence
API offers many possibilities to increase performance by
means of using many distributed cache frameworks.

So if cache implemented then this query you are running wont take that much time on second request.

(Though Off topic)On the other hand JPA relieves the
programmer from manual handling of persistent data in
CRUD operations, hence reducing the development time
and maintenance cost, it is enough to provide the data
base schema to generate automatically the most of the
CRUD operations needed to develop the system.

Answer (score 0):

Query itself takes the same time,  but hibernate does a lot of additional stuff (depending on settings and data model) which consumes time and memory
  - create object proxies for lazy loading
  - cache them into own cache
  - loading data into proxies in separate queries
  - create collection proxies for relations
  - ...  possibly eager loading them

Just activate hibernate trace, ans see what actually going on ( usually a lot of )

Comment: if a use a native query (entityManager.createNativeQuery) will i circumvent the additional stuff?

Comment: Yep.  But you will lose all the fancy stuff JPA provides for you. So you couild sticja s well with plain JDBC